# How add a C library to Windows?

Tags: c++, c, cygwin, qhull

I am new to the C programming language, and I have a C library. Based on the code writer statement [HERE](http://www.qhull.org/html/qvoronoi.htm), it compiles for 32-bit Windows and has a DLL file.

I want to know in detail, how can I add it to my PC in a way that compiler and IDE can find it easily. This library will be used in a program with the main structure written in the Fortran language.

I read the instrument of the library. There is something about installing the library. So I add a directory path to it.

Based on the readme in the library, I run this command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs qhullcpp qhullstatic_r` -o my_app my_app.cpp
```

and:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs qhullcpp qhull_r` -o my_app my_app.cpp
```

in the Cygwin with the "pkg-config" tool. It shows:

> Package qhullcpp was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
> you should add the directory containing `qhullcpp.pc' to the
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable Package 'qhullcpp', required by
> 'virtual:world', not found Package 'qhullstatic_r', required by
> 'virtual:world', not found g++.exe: error: my_app.cpp: No such file or
> directory g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

and:

> Package qhullcpp was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps
> you should add the directory containing `qhullcpp.pc' to the
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable Package 'qhullcpp', required by
> 'virtual:world', not found Package 'qhull_r', required by
> 'virtual:world', not found g++.exe: error: my_app.cpp: No such file or
> directory g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

respectively. Can anyone help to solve this problem and install the library?

I will appreciate any comments that give me a little help and forgive me for writing shortcomings.

Comment: *"in a way that compiler and IDE can find it easily"* - it is supposed to be the other way around - you need to provide information for compiler and IDE which libraries they should use and where those libraries are located. Typically this involves supplying preprocessor directives, include paths, library paths and list of libraries to link. If you are going to provide this information using pkg-config then you'll need to perform proper setup for pkg-config.

Comment: @user7860670 Thanks for the comment. Which way is easy and proper to provide information for the compiler and IDE? If I want to use "pkg-config", then I must use which setup and how?

Comment: There is no easy way... Setting up projects and managing dependencies has always been a pain point of C/C++ development. If you want to use pkg-config for some reason and developer didn't document its availability out of box then you'll need to figure out `.pc` file content yourself.

Comment: @user7860670 So, the statement: "Installing Qhull on Windows:
The zip file contains(...).  Qhull.exe and user-eg3.exe are compiled with the reentrant library while the other executables use the non-reentrant library.
To install Qhull:- Unzip the files into a directory (e.g., named 'qhull')- Click on QHULL-GO or open a command window into Qhull's bin directory." doesn't work and I must use a program like "CMAKE" to install it. Is it ok:?

Comment: Installation is a vague term. Windows have no built-in notion of installing source code components and unzipping is certainly not an installation. And installation of any kind is not required at all. You should instead focus on figuring out preprocessor directives, include paths, library paths and list of libraries to link required to use this library.

Comment: @user7860670 You add more confusion to my problem. I know it needs installation and also I read something about CMAKE and QT. But when I read the aim of these programs, can't find anything about the installation. "Installing Qhull with CMake:
   To build Qhull, static libraries, shared library, and C++ interface
    - cd build
  - cmake --help              
  - cmake -G "<generator>" ..   -- cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
  - cmake ..                   
  - make
  - ctest
  - make install"

Answer (score 0):

As you put the `cygwin` tag, be aware that the package is already available both
for 32bit and 64bit version of Cygwin

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2019-December/009360.html

```
$ cygcheck -cd |grep qhull
libqhull-devel                          2019.1-1
libqhull_7                              2019.1-1
qhull                                   2019.1-1
```

the import shared libraries are in the usual place

```
$ cygcheck -l libqhull-devel |grep dll
/usr/lib/libqhull.dll.a
/usr/lib/libqhull_p.dll.a
/usr/lib/libqhull_r.dll.a
```

as the include

```
$ cygcheck -l libqhull-devel |grep include

/usr/include/libqhull/DEPRECATED.txt
/usr/include/libqhull/geom.h
/usr/include/libqhull/index.htm
...
/usr/include/libqhullcpp/Coordinates.h
/usr/include/libqhullcpp/functionObjects.h
...
/usr/include/libqhull_r/geom_r.h
/usr/include/libqhull_r/index.htm
...
/usr/include/libqhull_r/user_r.h
```

Comment: How I import this command? are the produce .lib and .dll files? I use windows 7 64-bit